# Yarn add babel/preset-react fails

Tags: babeljs, yarnpkg

[Using the command recommended by the docs:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-react)

```
> yarn add @babel/preset-react --dev
yarn add v1.17.3
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel%2freact: Not found".
```

[According to the docs you can add git repo directly:](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add)

```
> yarn add https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-react --dev
yarn add v1.17.3
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel%2freact: Not found".
```

Comment: Seems to be a broader problem, no working solutions found yet: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5865